# template argument deduction/substitution failed. y?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <bool,typename T>
struct enabler
{

};

template <typename T>
struct enabler<true,T>
{
    typedef T type;
};


template <typename T>
void test1(typename enabler< is_integral<T>::value,T >::type input)
{
    cout << "this is for only integral" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test1(10);//error
    test1<int>(10); // compiles fine

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with error message.

note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed

note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’

When the parameter is explicitly specified, it is fine. But when it is not, compiler finds a problem in deducing. why?

Comment: why the downvote for this question?.

Comment: Note that you may replace your custor `enabler` by `std::enable_if` (`_t`).

Comment: You cannot deduce types left of a `::`.

Answer (score 2):

`T` in `typename enabler<is_integral<T>::value, T>::type` is non-deducible:

§ 14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/p5:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> <sup>(5.1)</sup> — The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.

An option is to place `enabler` in return type syntax and let `T` be deduced as a plain parameter:

```
template <typename T>
typename enabler<std::is_integral<T>::value, void>::type test1(T input)
{
    std::cout << "this is for only integral" << std::endl;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0354c895279a6c49)